# Send http form post attributes via https

Tags: java, html, forms, ssl, https

I'm using openshift which provides shared ssl so I'm able to access my website using https://url, my question is:

Should I need to change anything on my HTML form code or only at my servlet to secure data transfer from client to server?

Comment: the only thing you might need to change about the form is if you had used an absolute link in your form's `action=`, then you'd need to specify https, but if you're using relative paths like most people, you're fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As EdgeCaseBerg stated above, the biggest thing would be if you had explicit links that have the "http://" in them, which you would need to change to "https://".   You should be using relative links, and the browser will automatically form the right paths and query the server securely to fetch pages.

If you links are external to your site, there is no way to protect that transaction, unless they too are using SSL secured communications, then you would just make sure to use the "https://".  Unfortunately you can not guarantee that the site is safe, or running properly if it out of your control.

The only other gotchas I can think of is using URL based parameter passing.  Nothing in the URL is protected, but form post data is protected.  So you need to make sure you are using tokens, post data, hidden form fields, etc.. to pass data from page to page, from reload to reload to ensure the data passed between server and client is protected with the SSL encryption.